# error in the load xmlfile

Tags: php, xml, dom

I read everything I could about this error, but didn't find a solution. I have a simple page that looks like this:

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$objDOM->load(dirname(__FILE__) . 'goldbach.xml'); 
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("header");
```

And this is my xml file location:

```
Windows(C)>xampp>htdocs>smarthome>goldbach.xml
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What is the error? is the xml file in the same directory of your php file?

Comment: BTW: Use https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.is-readable.php to find out whether the path can be read. You'll be suprised!

Comment: this the error message

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:///C:/smarthome/goldbach.xml" in C:\xampp\htdocs\smarthome\parsingXML.php on line 5